# How to provide index-url to python setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to run "python setup.py test" and I have dependencies that are only accessible from custom index-url. I cannot edit any local configuration files like pip.ini as I only have access to svn directory of my project (this is a build on TeamCity).

Is this possible to provide setuptools with the custom index url in this case?